# Что такое ZO и NO в glm?

Tags: java, android, c++

пробую писать для android приложение и нужно переписывать с glm функцию ortho. пока не работает, не видно спрайта. я думаю что это из-за неправильного расчета glortho. но в glm их несколько. как мне сделать определение, чтобы в java нужный ortho вызывался? вот код glm.

```
template<typename T>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> ortho(T left, T right, T bottom, T top)
    {
        mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> Result(static_cast<T>(1));
        Result[0][0] = static_cast<T>(2) / (right - left);
        Result[1][1] = static_cast<T>(2) / (top - bottom);
        Result[2][2] = - static_cast<T>(1);
        Result[3][0] = - (right + left) / (right - left);
        Result[3][1] = - (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
        return Result;
    }

    template<typename T>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> orthoLH_ZO(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T zNear, T zFar)
    {
        mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> Result(1);
        Result[0][0] = static_cast<T>(2) / (right - left);
        Result[1][1] = static_cast<T>(2) / (top - bottom);
        Result[2][2] = static_cast<T>(1) / (zFar - zNear);
        Result[3][0] = - (right + left) / (right - left);
        Result[3][1] = - (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
        Result[3][2] = - zNear / (zFar - zNear);
        return Result;
    }

    template<typename T>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> orthoLH_NO(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T zNear, T zFar)
    {
        mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> Result(1);
        Result[0][0] = static_cast<T>(2) / (right - left);
        Result[1][1] = static_cast<T>(2) / (top - bottom);
        Result[2][2] = static_cast<T>(2) / (zFar - zNear);
        Result[3][0] = - (right + left) / (right - left);
        Result[3][1] = - (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
        Result[3][2] = - (zFar + zNear) / (zFar - zNear);
        return Result;
    }

    template<typename T>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> orthoRH_ZO(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T zNear, T zFar)
    {
        mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> Result(1);
        Result[0][0] = static_cast<T>(2) / (right - left);
        Result[1][1] = static_cast<T>(2) / (top - bottom);
        Result[2][2] = - static_cast<T>(1) / (zFar - zNear);
        Result[3][0] = - (right + left) / (right - left);
        Result[3][1] = - (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
        Result[3][2] = - zNear / (zFar - zNear);
        return Result;
    }

    template<typename T>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> orthoRH_NO(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T zNear, T zFar)
    {
        mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> Result(1);
        Result[0][0] = static_cast<T>(2) / (right - left);
        Result[1][1] = static_cast<T>(2) / (top - bottom);
        Result[2][2] = - static_cast<T>(2) / (zFar - zNear);
        Result[3][0] = - (right + left) / (right - left);
        Result[3][1] = - (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
        Result[3][2] = - (zFar + zNear) / (zFar - zNear);
        return Result;
    }

    template<typename T>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> orthoZO(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T zNear, T zFar)
    {
        if(GLM_CONFIG_CLIP_CONTROL & GLM_CLIP_CONTROL_LH_BIT)
            return orthoLH_ZO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
        else
            return orthoRH_ZO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
    }

    template<typename T>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> orthoNO(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T zNear, T zFar)
    {
        if(GLM_CONFIG_CLIP_CONTROL & GLM_CLIP_CONTROL_LH_BIT)
            return orthoLH_NO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
        else
            return orthoRH_NO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
    }

    template<typename T>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> orthoLH(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T zNear, T zFar)
    {
        if(GLM_CONFIG_CLIP_CONTROL & GLM_CLIP_CONTROL_ZO_BIT)
            return orthoLH_ZO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
        else
            return orthoLH_NO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);

    }

    template<typename T>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> orthoRH(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T zNear, T zFar)
    {
        if(GLM_CONFIG_CLIP_CONTROL & GLM_CLIP_CONTROL_ZO_BIT)
            return orthoRH_ZO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
        else
            return orthoRH_NO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
    }

    template<typename T>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, defaultp> ortho(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T zNear, T zFar)
    {
        if(GLM_CONFIG_CLIP_CONTROL == GLM_CLIP_CONTROL_LH_ZO)
            return orthoLH_ZO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
        else if(GLM_CONFIG_CLIP_CONTROL == GLM_CLIP_CONTROL_LH_NO)
            return orthoLH_NO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
        else if(GLM_CONFIG_CLIP_CONTROL == GLM_CLIP_CONTROL_RH_ZO)
            return orthoRH_ZO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
        else if(GLM_CONFIG_CLIP_CONTROL == GLM_CLIP_CONTROL_RH_NO)
            return orthoRH_NO(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
    }
```

я пробую программировать для opengles 300 es, и там как я знаю нужно свою ortho реализацию делать. LH как я понимаю это Left Hand, левая рука в opengl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NO` - *negative-one* - нормализация в диапазон `[-1 .. +1]`

`ZO` - *zero-one* - нормализация в диапазон `[0 .. +1]`

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!